# Need help: Discord Player FFMPEG Process Not Terminating Properly - Return Code -9

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

I am encountering an issue with Discord Player's FFMPEG process that is not terminating properly. I receive the following error message:

"INFO discord.player ffmpeg process 10984 has not terminated. Waiting to terminate...
INFO discord.player ffmpeg process 10984 should have terminated with a return code of -9"

I am not sure what this error means or how to fix it. I have attempted to restart my computer and the Discord bot, but the error persists. I have also checked for any updates to Discord and FFMPEG, but there are none available.

This error is preventing me from using Discord bot for streaming the audio, and I would appreciate any assistance in resolving it. If anyone has encountered this issue before or has any suggestions for how to fix it, I would be grateful for your help.

Thank you in advance.

## What i am expecting:

I am currently experiencing an issue with my Discord bot, where it is not able to play audio in the voice channel despite being provided with a valid URL. I have attempted to troubleshoot this issue by examining the bot's code and verifying that it is correctly configured to play audio in the voice channel.

Furthermore, I have checked the Discord API documentation and ensured that I am following the appropriate guidelines for playing audio in a voice channel. Additionally, I have verified that the bot has the necessary permissions to join and play audio in the voice channel.

However, despite my efforts, the bot is still unable to play audio in the voice channel. I am expecting the bot to play the audio once the URL is provided, but it does not appear to be functioning correctly.

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue and getting my bot to play audio in the voice channel as intended.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.